# How to calculate this derivative.

Tags: derivatives

How to get the last equation from the above set of equations.

[image]

In the book, it is mentioned straight away that the value of $P_0(t)$ is equal to that. I don't understand this step. How is it calculated?

Comment: In the book, it is mentioned straight away that the value of P0(t) is equal to that. I don;t understand this step. How it is calculated.

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like you are not calculating a derivative, but trying to solve a differential equation. If you've been through calculus, you would ideally recognize that if $f'(x) = -\alpha f(x)$ then $f(x) = Ce^{-\alpha x}$ where $C$ is some constant. If not, we can solve this differential equation pretty easily. The equation $$\frac{dP}{dt} = -\alpha P(t)$$ is known as a *separable* differential equation, since you can rewrite it as $$\begin{align}\frac{dP}{P(t)} = -\alpha dt \\ \implies \int \frac{dP}{P(t)} = \int -\alpha dt  \\ \implies \ln(P(t))+A = -\alpha t +B \\ \implies \ln(P(t)) = -\alpha t + C \\ \implies P(t) = e^{ -\alpha t + C} \\ = e^{-\alpha t }e^C\end{align}$$ Note that $e^C$ is just a constant, so let's call it $\tilde{C}$. Hence $$P(t) = \tilde{C}e^{-\alpha t}$$ Now we can use the initial condition that $P(0) = 1$, which means $$1= \tilde{C}e^{-\alpha \cdot 0 } = \tilde{C}e^{0} = \tilde{C}$$ and we conclude  $$P(t) = e^{ -\alpha t}$$

Comment: How is this integral dP/P(t) = ln(P(t)). Didn't understand this step.

Comment: Are you familiar with how to differentiate $\ln(x)$? If so, just use the chain rule to see that the derivative of $\ln(P(x))$ is $\frac{1}{P(t)} \cdot P'(t) = \frac{dP}{P(t)}$. If you integrate you go back to $\ln(P(t))$.

Comment: Well, thank you. I done all this like 15 years ago, seems like i am very rusty.

Comment: You are welcome. Good luck with the rest of your work!